# Using plotly.js 3d scatter3d with Webpack on Vue

Tags: webpack, vue.js, browserify, vue-loader

I'm trying to run plotly.js with webpack and Vue.js

for simple plot like scatter it's working fine with the following configuration:

on webpack.config.js

```
loaders: [
        {
            test: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'ify-loader'
        },

    ],
```

and in the vue file I import with the following code:

```
var Plotly = require('plotly.js/lib/core');
Plotly.register([
    require('plotly.js/lib/scatter'),
    require('plotly.js/lib/scatter3d'),
]);
```

with scatter everything works fine, but when I try to use:

```
type: 'scatter3d',
```

I receive the following error:

```
It appears that you're using glslify in browserify without its transform applied. Make sure that you've set up glslify as a source transform:
```

So by my understanding, I need to make ify-loader process my file projects besides the node_modules.

I already tried to insert the transform on my project as recommend on the GitHub readme [Link for the docs](https://github.com/browserify/ify-loader#using-transforms-in-your-project) but neither test works (with .js and .vue) :

With .js

```
    loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'ify-loader',
            enforce: 'post'
        }
     ]
```

With .vue

```
loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'ify-loader',
            enforce: 'post'
        }
     ]
```

Any tips, or clue how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

```
import Plotly from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly.min'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Using `require('plotly.js-dist')` (not `import`) solves the problem.